# Are any of the countries in Hard to Be a God based specifically on particular real-life countries?

Tags: russian-language, strugatsky-brothers, setting, hard-to-be-a-god, allegory

Arkanar, Irukan, Soan, ... there are several countries mentioned and given at least *some* description and fleshing out in the book. **Are any of these intended to be direct parallels of specific real-life countries?**

I could see Arkanar being the USSR, especially since [Don Reba is based on the Soviet figure Beria](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2238/17), but there could also be elements of the Spanish Inquisition in Reba's pogroms. Is there any evidence, either from the text itself or from interviews with the authors, for Arkanar or any of the other countries mentioned being modelled on particular countries in the real world?

Comment: I've skimmed through Boris Strugatsky's [off-line interview](http://www.rusf.ru/abs/int_t20.htm) about _Hard to be a God_, and I don't think this has been asked before.

Comment: Arkanar can't be the USSR: it isn't communist. Arkanar could be pre-Soviet Russia, if it was parallel to a real-life country. But I don't think they are supposed to parallel specific countries, rather they're all following a historical mold which was seen throughout Europe (if you look at history with the right blinders, at least).

Comment: @Gilles I'd accept an answer which argues convincingly that they aren't supposed to parallel specific countries.

Comment: @Gilles - you're technically correct yet wrong. It's about feudalism sliing into fascism; and Strugatskys explicitly equated Stalinism to fascism where classes replace nationalities (see the fascism article link in my answer).

Comment: @DVK The Strugatskys didn't *explicitly* equate Stalinism to fascism. Even after 1956 that would have made it impossible for them to be published in the USSR.

Comment: @Gilles - That logic would be correct, except said equivalence wasn't in a book published during Soviet times (at least, explicitly). [It was in a post-Perestroyka published article about dangers of fascism in modern day Russia published by Boris Strugatsky](http://www.hro.org/node/2925).

Comment: @Gilles I spotted a line today in one of the later chapters which explicitly used the word "communist" to refer to the regime in Arkanar. I can't remember exactly where it was (will try to hunt it down again), and it *may* have been just a bad translation, but I thought it was worth noting.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Looking at a greppable version, this is Rumata imagining ***future*** Arkanar, about 3/4 of the way through part 7.

Comment: @Gilles - yes, you're absolutely correct (confirming from Russian text) - he is addressing the imaginary inhabitants of *future* Communist Arkanar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Original Authorial Intent:

- #### "Three Musketeers"-ish pre-Age-of-Discovery kinda-Spain-cum-Russia-or-France (sans muskets).

Based on Boris Strugatsky's "[Commentaries to the past](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/55082/21/Strugackiii_-_Kommentarii_k_proiidennomu.html)" (which comments on most of their works in great detail), quoting the original 1963 letter from Arkady Strugatsky where the idea of the book was discussed:

> «...Существует где-то планета, точная копия Земли, можно с небольшими отклонениями, **в эпоху непосредственно перед Великими географическими открытиями**. Абсолютизм, веселые пьяные мушкетеры, кардинал, король, мятежные принцы, инквизиция, матросские кабаки, галеоны и фрегаты, красавицы, веревочные лестницы, серенады и пр. **И вот в эту страну (помесь Франции с Испанией, или России с Испанией)** ...
>
> ... **Это можно написать весело и интересно, как «Три мушкетера», только со средневековой мочой и грязью, как там пахли женщины, и в вине была масса дохлых мух.**

Translation mine (as usual):

> «... There is a planet somewhere, an copy of the Earth with small deviations, **in the era just before the Age of Discovery**. Absolutism, merry drunk musketeers, cardinal, king, rebellious princes, inquisition, sailors' taverns, galleons and frigates, beauties, rope ladders, serenades, etc. **And in this country (a cross between France and Spain, or Russia and Spain)** ...
>
> You can write this in a fun and interesting way, kind of like "Three Musketeers", **except with middle-ageish urine and mud;** with stinky women and a bunch of dead flies in the wine.

Just for cultural context - the writings of Alexander Dumas, especially *The Three Musketeers*, were incredibly popular in the USSR, far more so than generally in the West.

---

---

---

## Textually:

- ## Arkanar is in some ways based on Third Reich.

  Don Rumata equates the events of the Holy Order's takeover with what happened in Germany.

  1. First, there was oblique:

     > А ведь можно было догадаться, думал Румата. **Там, где торжествует серость, к власти всегда приходят черные**. Эх, историки, хвостом вас по голове... Но он заложил руки за спину и покачался с носков на пятку.

     > You know, I could have guessed, thought Rumata. **Wherever grayness triumphs, black robes come to power**. Oh, historians, stick a tail in all of you… But he put his hands behind his back and rocked from toe to heel.
     > <sub>From the 2014 translation.</sub>

     For those who didn't quite catch the historical allusion yet (it will be more explicit in later text referenced below), this was implying the events of the "[Night of the Long Knives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Long_Knives)".
  2. Second, they explicitly called the burger guards "[stormtroopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung)"

     > На ступеньках сидел, пригорюнясь, серый **штурмовик**, поставив боевой топор между коленей

     > The grey **stormtrooper** sat sadly on the stairs...
  3. Rumata explicitly referenced [a well known point in Reich history (The night of the Long Knives)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Long_Knives) in reference to soon-to-be-dead Father Tzupik, a captain of the Grey stormtroopers and the head of palace guard:

     > Отец же Цупик, как человек военный и бывший бакалейщик, лицом владеть не умел. Он мрачнел, кусал губу, пальцы его на рукояти меча сжимались и разжимались; и в конце концов он вдруг дернул щекой, резко повернулся и, нарушая все правила, пошел вон из опочивальни прямо на толпу оцепеневших от такой невоспитанности придворных. Дон Рэба, извинительно улыбаясь, поглядел ему вслед, а Румата, проводив глазами нескладную серую фигуру, подумал: «Вот и еще один покойник». Ему было известно о трениях между доном Рэбой и серым руководством. **История коричневого капитана Эрнста Рема готова была повториться**.

     > Father Zupik, as a military man and a former grocer, could not control his face. ... turned sharply and, violating all the rules, went out of the bedchamber ... Don Reba, with an apologetic smile, looked after him, and Rumata, seeing with his eyes an incoherent gray figure, thought: "There's another dead man." He was aware of the friction between Don Reba and the gray leadership. **The story of the brown captain [Ernst Röhm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_R%C3%B6hm) was ready to be repeated**.
  4. Rumata also compared Arkanar events to fascism to Don Condor:

     > И когда я говорю ему о фашизме, о серых штурмовиках, об активизации мещанства, он воспринимает это как эмоциональные выражения

     > And when I tell him about fascism, about the gray stormtroopers, about the intensification of burgeousie, he perceives this as emotional expression.
  5. Finally, Rumata explicitly calls the Order-invaded Arkanar "feudal-**fascist**" base of aggression:

     > ... вылилось в провокационную интригу Святого Ордена и привело к превращению Арканара в базу **феодально‑фашистской агрессии**

     > ... Resulted in the provocation based intrigue of the Holy Order and led to the transformation of Arkanar into the base of **feudal-fascist aggression**

     As a side note, in a later publication, Boris Strugatsky ([criticizing nationalists in Russia in "Фашизм - это очень просто" ("Fascism - it's quite simple")](http://www.hro.org/node/2925)) explicitly equated fascism with feudalism and feudal mentality:

     > Могу легко представить себе человека, который, ознакомившись со всеми этими моими дефинициями, скажет (с сомнением): "Этак у тебя получается, что лет пятьсот-шестьсот назад все на свете были фашистами - и князья, и цари, и сеньоры, и вассалы..."
     > В каком-то смысле такое замечание бьет в цель, ибо оно верно "с точностью до наоборот": **фашизм - это задержавшийся в развитии феодализм**, переживший и век пара, и век электричества, и век атома, и готовый пережить век космических полетов и искусственного интеллекта. Феодальные отношения, казалось бы, исчезли, но феодальный менталитет оказался живуч и могуч, он оказался сильнее и пара, и электричества, сильнее всеобщей грамотности и всеобщей компьютеризации.
     > Живучесть его, безусловно, имеет причиной то обстоятельство, что корнями своими феодализм уходит в дофеодальные, еще пещерные времена, в ментальность блохастого стада бесхвостых обезьян: все чужаки, живущие в соседнем лесу, - отвратительны и опасны, а вожак наш великолепно жесток, мудр и побеждает врагов. Эта первобытная ментальность, видимо, не скоро покинет род человеческий. **И поэтому фашизм - это феодализм сегодня**. И завтра.

     > I can easily imagine a person who, having become acquainted with all these definitions of mine, will say (with doubt): "So it turns out that five hundred or six hundred years ago everyone in the world was fascists - princes, kings, senyors, and vassals ... "
     > In a sense, that hits the mark, for it is true "in reverse": **fascism is the feudalism that has lingered in development**, survived the age of steam, the age of electricity, and the age of the atom, and is ready to survive the age of space flights and Artificial Intelligence. Feudal relations seemed to have disappeared, but the feudal mentality proved to be tenacious and powerful, it proved to be stronger than steam and electricity, stronger than universal literacy and universal computerization.
     > Its vitality, of course, is due to the fact that the roots of its feudalism go back to prefeudal, caveman times, to the mentality of the flea-infested group of tailless monkeys: all strangers living in the neighboring forest are disgusting and dangerous, and our leader is superbly cruel, wise and Defeats the Enemies. This primitive mentality, apparently, will not leave the human race anytime soon. **And so fascism is feudalism today**. And tomorrow.

Ironically, the original intent contradicts these parallels; the book was supposed to be a pure historical adventure without deep subtext and obvious links to modernity. Quoting from "Commentaries on the past" again; another ANS letter:

> А мне хотелось создать повесть об абстрактном благородстве, чести и радости, как у Дюма. И не смей мне противоречить. **Хоть одну-то повесть без современных проблем в голом виде.** На коленях прошу, мерзавец! Шпаг мне, шпаг! Кардиналов! Портовых кабаков!

> But I wanted to create a story about abstract nobility, honor and joy, Dumas-like. And don't you dare contradict me. **At least one story without modern problems in their naked form.** I beg you on my knees, scoundrel! Give me Épées! The Cardinals! Port taverns!

---

- #### Republic of Soan clearly seems based on Republic of Venice

  1. Trade Republic with heavy maritime trade:

     > ни тем более в торговой республике Соан, давно уже пустившей все свои леса на корабли

     > Nor even more so in the trading republic of Soan, which had long ago used all its forests to build ships
  2. Led by a [12-member council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Council_of_Venice) of patricians:

     > ... дон Кондор, Генеральный судья и Хранитель больших государственных печатей торговой республики Соан, вице‑президент Конференции двенадцати негоциантов

     > Don Condor, General Custodian and Custodian of large state seals of the commercial republic of Soan, Vice President of the **Conference of Twelve Traders**

     Yet he's a high ranking noble, outranking Rumata who's considered ancient nobility of the Empire:

     > но ноги, следуя этикету, сами собой согнулись в коленях, шпоры торжественно звякнули, правая рука описала широкий полукруг от сердца и в сторону, а голова нагнулась так, что подбородок утонул в пенно‑кружевных брыжах. Дон Кондор сорвал бархатный берет с простым дорожным пером, торопливо, как бы отгоняя комаров, махнул им в сторону Руматы, а затем, швырнув берет на стол, обеими руками расстегнул у шеи застежки плащ

     > but his legs observed the proper etiquette in spite of himself and bent at the knees. His spurs jingled solemnly, his right hand swept out an arc starting at his heart and ending at his side, and his head bent down so that his chin sank into the foamy lace ruff. Don Condor ripped off his plumed velvet beret, hastily waved it in Rumata’s direction, as if he were chasing off mosquitoes, flung it on the table, and undid the clasps of his cloak at his neck with both hands.
     > <sub>From the 2014 translation</sub>

---

- #### Overall, all the kingdoms seem based on feudal medieval Europe.

  > У нас безотказное оружие – **базисная теория феодализма**, разработанная в тиши кабинетов и лабораторий, на пыльных раскопах, в солидных дискуссиях…

  > We have a foolproof weapon — **the basis theory of feudalism**, developed in quiet offices and laboratories, at dusty archaeological digs, in thoughtful discussions.
  > <sub>From the 2014 translation</sub>
  >
  > центробежные процессы в древней Империи стали значимыми. Воспользовавшись этим, Святой Орден, представлявший, по сути, интересы наиболее реакционных групп **феодального общества**, которые любыми средствами стремились приостановить диссипацию...

  > the centrifugal processes in the ancient empire became relevant. Taking advantage of this, the Holy Order, essentially representing the interests of the most reactionary groups of **feudal society**, who desired to stop the disintegration by any means necessary…
  > <sub>From the 2014 translation</sub>
  >
  > **В полном соответствии с базисной теорией феодализма**,– он яростно поглядел прямо в глаза дону Кондору,– это самое заурядное выступление горожан против баронства,– он перевел взгляд на дона Гуга,– вылилось в провокационную интригу Святого Ордена и привело к превращению Арканара в базу феодально‑фашистской агрессии.

  > **In full accordance with the basis theory of feudalism**,” he furiously looked Don Condor in the eye, “this commonplace rebellion of the citizens against the barony,” he shifted his gaze to Don Gug, “turned into a provocative intrigue by the Holy Order and resulted in the transformation of Arkanar into a base of feudal-fascist aggression.
  > <sub>From the 2014 translation</sub>

  Then of course we have all the Walter-Scottish (or, musket-less Alexander-Dumas-like) trappings of the fiction book set in medieval times: with swords, crossbows, plate armour, feudal noble lords, smalltime tradesmen, witch hunts, palace intrigues, alchemists, court poets, lack of hygiene, taverns, etc...)

  Dumas's work obviously influenced the book, by the way - even if you ignore the authorial intent discussed at the beginning of the answer:

  1. There are even allusions to Dumas's characters (falsely comparing Don Reba to Cardinal Richelieu)
  2. At one point, "Three Musketeers" line is directly quoted by Pashka:

     > Меня зовут Бон Саранча,– неохотно признался Пашка.– «*И здесь он, по‑видимому, ляжет – один из тех, что были с ним*».

     > My name is Bon Locust, Pashka reluctantly admitted. "*And here, apparently, he will lie down - one of those who were with him.*"

     According to Lyudeny group (main experts on Strugatsky in Russian interwebz), [Pashka's quote is from the 1936 Russian translation of *The Three Musketeers*](http://www.rusf.ru/abs/ludeni/tbb.htm):

     > С. 24. «И здесь он, по-видимому, ляжет – один из тех, что были с ним». – А. Дюма, «Три мушкетера», 1, 5: «– *Здесь, – сказал он, пародируя стих из Библии, – здесь умрет Бикара, единый из тех, которые с ним*». Перевод под ред. А. Попова. Издание романа: М.-Л.: Academia, 1936, с. 87. Оригинальная цитата из Дюма: «*Ici, dit-il, parodiant un verset de la Bible, ici mourra Biscarat, seul de ceux qui sont avec lui*». Библейский источник пародии – Откровение Иоанна (17, 14): «...Он есть Господь господствующих и Царь царей, и те, которые с Ним, суть званые и избранные и верные» («...qu'il est le Seigneur des seigneurs et le Roi des rois, et les appelés, les élus et les fidèles qui sont avec lui les vaincront aussi»).

---

## Subtextually:

- #### Events in Arkanar symbolized 1963 attacks of Communist state on culture.

  (for context, in December 1962, among the general end of the "thaw", Nikita Khruschyov lambasted [abstract artists' exhibition at Manezh](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) which opened a [witch-hunt on various cultural figures from Soviet powers that be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Nonconformist_Art#1962_.E2.80.93_mid-1970s)).

  This is discussed in detail in the next part of HTBAG chapted in "Commentaries to the Past":

  > Осознание этих простых, но далеко для нас не очевидных тогда истин было мучительно, как всякое осознание истины, но и благотворно в то же время. Новые идеи появились и настоятельно потребовали своего немедленного воплощения. Вся задуманная нами «веселая, мушкетерская» история стала смотреться совсем в новом свете, и БНу не потребовалось долгих речей, чтобы убедить АНа в необходимости существенной идейной коррекции «Наблюдателя». Время «легкомысленных вещей», время «шпаг и кардиналов», видимо, закончилось. А может быть, просто еще не наступило. **Мушкетерский роман должен был, обязан был стать романом о судьбе интеллигенции, погруженной в сумерки средневековья**.

  > The realization of these truths, simple but back then far from obvious to us,  was painful, like any awareness of the truth, but also beneficial at the same time. New ideas emerged and urgently demanded their immediate implementation. All the "merry, musketeerish" story that we conceived was viewed in a new light, and it did not take Boris long speeches to convince Arkady of the need for a substantial ideological correction of the "Observer". The time of "frivolous things", the time of "swords and cardinals", apparently ended. Or maybe it just has not come yet. **The Musketeer novel was supposed to, had to, become a novel about the fate of the intelligentsia, immersed in the twilight of the Middle Ages**.